# How to make jquery work on a page that was called by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling a page using ajax, I have jquery on that page but it doesn't work when I call the page. Here is the code example.

```
<a href="javascript:();" onclick="getdata('page.php','example');">Load Page</a>
<div id='example'></div>
```

On the page that loads

```
<script>
 $( function() {
   $("#divexample").click( function() {
       $(this).css("background-color","red")
     })
 });
</script>

<div id='divexample'></div>
```

The Jquery doesn't work on that page.

I have seen people talking about .live which is deprecated and .on should be used, but I haven't been able to get that to work either. I have also tried to include the Jquery script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

On the page to see if it would reload the jquery...

Thanks for anyone's help! Just LOST!

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in your console?

Comment: You should show how you load the `page.php` and how you add the received html code to you document. Because it depends on how the script is loaded/added, if is executed and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `page.php` you only get static HTML back, no JavaScript will fire. Once you load into your page you need need to call any functions that would normally bind event handlers to your DOM elements. You cannot use the $(document).ready() to do this because that event has already fired.

You should structure your code to allow for this, something like:

```
var bindHandlers = function() {
    $("#divexample").click( function() {
       $(this).css("background-color","red")
    })
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    bindHandlers();
})
```

Addd in your callback of your load event when you click the button. You should not use the inline `onclick` handler and instead use jQuery to bind these events in the `ready()` event.

```
$('a.loadPage').on('click', function() {
    $('#example').load('page.php #divexample', bindHandlers);
]);
```

Alternatively, you can use the new [delegation features](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) of `.on()` and event bubbling.

```
$("#example").on('click', '#divexample', function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Using this, the event handler is bound to `#example` and will fire when the event bubbles up and matches `#divexample`. You can add whatever content you wish to #example and not have to rebind the handlers, this works in much the same way a `.live()` used to work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JRXCF/